# Generic container initialization failed for cucumter tests

Tags: java, docker, cucumber, docker-container, wiremock

I am trying to initialize and start a docker container from cucumber hooks in order to write integration tests, uing wiremock.

But the issue, is that initialization fails miserably for some reason.

Here the code snipped i have :

```
 @BeforeAll(order = 50)
    public static void prepareMockServer2() {
        var mockServer= new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("wiremock/wiremock"))
            .withExposedPorts(WIREMOCK_INTERNAL_PORT)
            .withClasspathResourceMapping("wiremock/modules/custom-service", "/home/wiremock", BindMode.READ_ONLY);
        mockServer.start();
        logger.info("server started");
    }
```

This folder `wiremock/modules/custom-service` is also in the `resources` folder.

Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration```

I expect normally the mock server to start.

But i get the following exception :

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed for image wiremock/wiremock:latest
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:349)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322)
    at net.haulogy.hauerp.esb.steps.CucumberHooks.prepareMeciMockServer2(CucumberHooks.java:71)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322)
    at net.haulogy.hauerp.esb.steps.CucumberHooks.prepareMeciMockServer2(CucumberHooks.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invokeStatic(Invoker.java:80)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStaticHookDefinition.execute(JavaStaticHookDefinition.java:49)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.executeHook(Runner.java:112)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.lambda$executeHooks$2(Runner.java:99)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.executeHooks(Runner.java:99)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runBeforeAllHooks(Runner.java:89)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runBeforeAllHooks(CucumberExecutionContext.java:94)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.runBeforeAllHooks(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:101)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineDescriptor.ifChildren(CucumberEngineDescriptor.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineDescriptor.before(CucumberEngineDescriptor.java:26)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineDescriptor.before(CucumberEngineDescriptor.java:11)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteLauncher.execute(SuiteLauncher.java:63)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestDescriptor.execute(SuiteTestDescriptor.java:128)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestEngine.lambda$execute$0(SuiteTestEngine.java:73)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.suite.engine.SuiteTestEngine.execute(SuiteTestEngine.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:553)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [52290] should be listening)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:101)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:52)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:964)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:490)
    ... 85 more
testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:321)
```

Any thoughts please to how can i fix this ?

Comment: Read the whole Stacktrace, then look at the logs of the container.

Comment: I did, there’s nothing in the container logs, no logs in the container.

Comment: If nothing happens, that probably explains why the container doesn't open the port.

Comment: Actually it starts, but since i am using it as a hook, there isn’t much in the logs, the startup logs of witemock.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out next why the port didn't open.

Comment: Exactly the point of my question, what could be the possibilities.

Comment: Your code probably doesn't do what you think it does. Can you get the docker to work by manually executing docker commands? Have you compared those commands to your java code?

Comment: Also what is the value of `WIREMOCK_INTERNAL_PORT`

Comment: A value an exposed port, which i  will supposedly call from an endpoint.

Comment: And does the container actually serve anything on that port?

Comment: It starts and closes abruptly after port issue.